# Galois Group of a Splitting field of $x^8-4$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^8-4$, I know that $|Gal(L/\Bbb Q)|=8$, but I have no idea what is the next step.

Comment: I'm assuming by $Q$ you mean the rationals. If not, please correct this.

Comment: NB $f(x)$ factors over $\Bbb Q$ as $(x^4 + 2)(x^4 - 2)$, so $\text{Gal}(L / {\Bbb Q}) \leq S_4 \times S_4$.

Answer (score 0):

An intermediate step might be to first prove that $L = \Bbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]{2})$ can be viewed as the splitting field for the irreducible polynomial $x^4 - 2$.  You can view the Galois group as the corresponding subgroup of $S_4$ acting on the four roots of $x^4-2$.

If you can't determine which permutations of the roots  are possible, there is a way to use the decomposition to break up the problem.  The Galois correspondence then says that $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\Bbb Q)$ will be generated by the automorphisms of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\Bbb Q(i))$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}))$, so you can first determine the maps that are in those subgroups, and then see what their group structure is under composition.

Comment: Note that the group has order 8, and is a subgroup of $S_4$, so it is a 2-sylow subgroup of $S_4$. Since all 2-sylow subgroups are conjugate, one just needs to find one.